# centering background image vertically

Tags: css, background-image, centering

I can't figure out how to center an image. It is cut when I use 'center center' as background position , the girl's head is not showing. Ahem.

```
body {
    background: url(http://media.silabg.com/uf/common/catch-the-sun01.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TomasRR/xvjdow6j/

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define some heights so the image knows how/where it should be centered:

```
html {
    height: 500px;
}

body {
    background: url("http://media.silabg.com/uf/common/catch-the-sun01.jpg") no-repeat center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/az6x908x/

Comment: Just add height:100% to the HTML instead of 500px. Then it will fillout the height of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center the image horizontally and vertically you can try:

```
body {
    background: url(http://media.silabg.com/uf/common/catch-the-sun01.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you Brent11, I was looking more for the solution that Thomas suggested but yours is good as well.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the background image vertically and horizontally centered. check **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/xvjdow6j/6/)**.

```
body {
    background: url(http://media.silabg.com/uf/common/catch-the-sun01.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50% fixed;
}
```